# Variables Not subtracting in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, subtraction

does anyone know why I can't subtract a variable from another variable if both are defined as numbers?

```
A = 100

B = int(input("Amount? "))
A - B
print(A)
```

This is a very simplified version of what it actually is but still the same concept, I am quite new to coding so sorry if this is really dumb of me to ask. Thanks :)

Comment: It works for me. Are you getting an error? If so, please add it to your question.

Comment: You subtract but the result goes to nowhere. To modify "A" write "A -= B".

Answer (score 1):

Replace `A - B` to `A = A - B` or use the shorthand notation `A -= B` which is the same as the first alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You are never assigning the value to A.
Here is the corrected code:

```
A = 100

B = int(input("Amount? "))
A = A - B #Issue was here
print(A)
```